# How to invoke getter and setter method for lombok in java?

Tags: java, lombok

I am new to lombok project for setters and getter in java. How can I invoke these methods if my class is like this:

```
@Entity(name="Users")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;
```

if I create the new object of Users like

```
Users user = new Users();
```

then `user.getClass()` is the only suggestion I am getting. How can I so user.get..  OR `user.set`?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is it aware of Lombok / are you using a plugin for your IDE to make it understand Lombok? If not, it's not going to suggest to you the methods that Lombok would automatically generate.

Comment: m using intellij

Comment: i have a better question: how do you put a breakpoint inside a setter generated by lombok? ;) #AntiLombokMafia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had also this problem. In order to use Lombok, you need to install lombok plugin for specific IDE. Here is a link for intellij and eclipse: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide